# Ajax call function on success return false not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am running an ajax request, then once I get the result back I choose if it should be continued or if the form should not submit. I am checking if the email exists.

Issue is I moved the return false out of the `success:` as it was not working there and now in a seperate function it is not working either. I get the `alert("FALSE");` but the form still submits which is no good as I want an error pop up to happen.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/ajax/checkdata.php",
  data: "email="+email,
  success: function(data){
    var returned = true;
    if (data == "Email Exists") {
      returned = false;
    } else {
    }
    emailModal(returned);
  }
})

function emailModal(result){
  if (result) {
    alert("TRUE");
  } else {
    alert("FALSE");
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: The call is async, it's too late to return something to the form at that point

Comment: so how can I achieve this as the async : false didn't seem to make a difference before

Comment: To be clear, your requirement is that you want to execute an AJAX request on submission of the form, and the result of that request determines whether or not the submission should be allowed to continue - is that correct?

Comment: Yep thats correct

Comment: @adeneo's answer nailed it then :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd have to always prevent the form from submitting, and then in the check for the email figure out wether to show an error or submit the form using the **native** submit handler

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/ajax/checkdata.php",
        data: {email : email},
        context: this
    }).done(function(data) {
        if (data == "Email Exists") {
            alert(data);
        } else {
            this.submit();
        }
    });
});
```